# How to Uninstall a program using msiexec with program guid to pass an argument with c#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, windows-installer

There are lots of program so if i know its guid value how can i uninstall using msiexec.exe from c#

```
public void msi(string path)
    {
        //get msiexec.exe /X{GUID} from path
        int slash = path.IndexOf(@"/");
        //get the substring as /I{GUID}
        String value = path.Substring(slash, (path.Length) - slash);
        MessageBox.Show(value);
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"msiexec.exe";

        process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(value);//Error is in this line 
        //`i just want to know how to pass the agrument to msiexec from c#`


        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

    }
```

Comment: If all you need is the right way to invoke msiexec, then this isn't really a C# question, is it?  It's `msiexec /x {guid}` https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/296067

Comment: i want to call msiecec with c# and send the uninstall value as an argument

Comment: So use string concatenation! Also, give us an example of what `path` may be.

Comment: please help me out with this

Comment: the path is msiexec.exe /X{A4BFF20C-A21E-4720-88E5-79D5A5AEB2E8}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the support this code works for me

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
        //The argument that you want to give
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/X{0784DF00-13E1-40D1-8BC4-E081AD2DA509}";
        p.Start();
```